# Track redirects when using sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5

How can I invoke custom code when a redirect happens while sending a request with the method:

```
+ (void)sendAsynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request queue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse*, NSData*, NSError*))handler
```

?

I'm looking to replicate the behavior the NSURLConnectionDelegate method:

```
- (NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)redirectResponse
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can replicate the behavior, since `sendAsynchronousRequest` only calls the completion handler given to it in the code block.

It seems that you must use the delegate method for this purpose. I don't see any benefit from using `sendAsynchronousRequest` over the normal `NSURLConnection`, except for the fact that you have to keep an ivar of NSMutableData and possibly NSURLConnection if there are multiple of them per instance of the class.